# How to send a push notification to a particular user at particular time after user's registration?

Tags: node.js

I want to send a push notification to a user **after it's registration** using FCM.

At the following times

- after **5 mins** of registration
- after **24 hours** of registration
- after **1 week** of registration

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You can use something like node-scheduler. Will post a sample code how you can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

let scheduleDate = new Date(Some date)

      schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleDate, function(fcmtoken){
        SendNotificationhere(fcmtoken)
    }.bind(null,fcmtoken))
```

If any doubt do mention your doubts in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Sending 5 minutes after registration can be done with `setInterval`. But for 24hours and 1 week you need to have some cron job running. You can use something `node-schedule` as suggested by @PratapSharma.

Since you won't have cron job for individual user. You need to have a cron job running every hour or so, which will check user registration time and based on difference send particular notification. You can fetch users which are registered within last few days, in your case it will be 7 days.

This approach will have variation of 59 minutes from actual time (in case of 24 hours or 7 days). You can make your diffing mechanism smarter. Probably include users between 23.5 hours to 24.5 hours. Similar approach you can take for 7 days.